# Change colour of tag upon document load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the colour of an element within my nav bar to give the effect of a selected page upon the document load. However, the code I have concocted (new to JS) is not working; no colour change occurs. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.onLoad = (function() {
            var nav = document.getElementById('textContainer');

            var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');

            var activeItem = navItems[0];

            activeItem.style.color = "#696969";
        });

</script>

<div id="header">
    <a href="#">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="navigation">
    <div id="textContainer">
        <h2><a href="#works">Works</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#blog">Blog</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h2>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `window.onload = ....` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `document.onLoad` with `window.onload`. Problem solved.

JavaScript is not HTML. Hence, it's case-sensitive. In HTML, global event handlers are attached to `<body>`. In JavaScript, global methods have to be defined on `window`.

Methods to bind an event listener:

```
window.onload = function(){...};                         // Works universally
window.addEventListener("load", function(){...}, false); // @All decent browsers
window.attachEvent("onload", function(){...});           // IE-only
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$("#textContainer h2 a").first().css("color","green");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fully working code

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


        var nav = document.getElementById('textContainer');

        var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');

        var activeItem = navItems[0];

        activeItem.style.color = "#696969";
});
</script>

<div id="header">
<a href="#">
<div id="logo"></div>
</a>
<div id="navigation">
<div id="textContainer">
    <h2><a href="#works">Works</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#blog">Blog</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Wat**? Adding a bloated library, just for a simple load event? If you really want to port the code to jQuery, the right way would be: `$(function(){$("#textContainer a").eq(1).css("color", "#696969")});`. But, as someone else has pointed out in another comment, this question is **not** about jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not being deselected now, would you mind taking a look? http://jsfiddle.net/hJSrW/